# VS2008 form in design mode displays at center

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, alignment

My problem is the form always displays at center in design mode and I cannot find the setting for this.

You can check the images below.

This form always shows at the center:
[image: This form always shows at the center]

But I want it to display like this:
[image: This is displaying in the left side]

You can see that be above 2 forms are in the same project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.